# Moving html table content to sql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got a table (grabbed from another website using php) but now I want to import it's content into my database (instead of just printing out the table).

This is the printout (https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnbAo.png) from the table using the following code:

```
<?php
$uitvoer = getTable();
echo "<table">;
foreach ($uitvoer as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $col) {
        echo "<td>" . $col . "</td>";
    }
echo "</tr>";
}
echo"</table>";
?>
```

And when I try this nothing happens to my database:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("mysql1.000webhost.com","a2902119_lowavol","pswd")
$uitvoer = getTable();
foreach ($uitvoer as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $col) {
        $query += "'" . $col . "', ";
    }
$sql="INSERT INTO test (cel1, cel2, cel3, cel4, cel5, cel6, cel7, cel8, cel9) VALUES ($query)";
mysqli_query($con, $sql);
}
?>
```

I have little to no knowledge about PHP. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: possible duplicate of [filling a database with html table content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18868749/filling-a-database-with-html-table-content)

Comment: You're close, you just have to remove the extra comma at the end of the `VALUES` list.

Comment: Since you're using mysqli, it would be better to use a prepared statement instead of concatenating strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The concatenation operator for PHP is (.) and not (+)**

```
  <?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("mysql1.000webhost.com","a2902119_lowavol","pswd")
    $uitvoer = getTable();
    foreach ($uitvoer as $row) {
       $query = array();
       $insert = "";
       $insert_values = "";
       foreach ($row as $col) {
           $query[] = $col;
       }
       $insert_values = implode("','", $query) ;
       $insert = "'".$insert_values."'";
       $sql = "INSERT INTO test (cel1, cel2, cel3, cel4, cel5, cel6, cel7, cel8, cel9) VALUES ($insert)";
       mysqli_query($con, $sql);
  }
?>
```

Comment: works! thanks just had to use the $querry[] = strip_tags($col); instead of $querry[] = $col; to remove html tags before entering them in the database! AWESOME

Comment: happy to have helped!

Comment: is there a way to put the first 5 rows in table A and the last 5 rows in table B if there were 10 tables in total?
So just splitting the number of rows in two and deviding the first half and second half over two different tables?

Comment: 10 tables or 10 rows?

Answer (score 1):

your query will look like this:

```
INSERT INTO test (....) VALUES (val, val, val, )
```

which is obviously a syntax error... try and add the fields to an array instead:

```
foreach ($uitvoer as $row) {
    $fields = array();
    foreach ($row as $col) {
        $fields[] = $col; // TODO: add escaping!
    }
// now you can build the values list with implode
$values = implode(', ', $fields);
$sql="INSERT INTO test (...) VALUES ($values)";
```

See [the docs about `implode()`](http://www.php.net/implode) for more info.

Comment: i'm almost there thanks!
but in the echo of the prepared sql statement there are a lot of returns i'm thinking this could be the reason no data is in the database yet? see link http://thomasdemarez.site88.net/heren1kfetch.php

Comment: try `$fields[] = trim($col);`, although those returns should not be a problem.

Comment: Looking at the source though, your values are containing HTML!

Answer (score 0):

Use a prepared statement:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO test (cel1, cel2, cel3, cel4, cel5, cel6, cel7, cel8, cel9) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssssssss", $row[0], $row[1], $row[2], $row[3], $row[4], $row[5], $row[6], $row[7], $row[8]);
foreach ($uitvoer as $row) {
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work.. I get two errors when loading the page
          1. Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /home/a2902119/public_html/heren1kfetch.php on line 22
          2. Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /home/a2902119/public_html/heren1kfetch.php on line 20

Answer (score -1):

Try echo-ing `$sql`. I think there is a comma in the end.

Use

```
$query = substr($query, 0, strlen($query) - 1)
```

in order to remove the last character of `$query`

(edited the command)